# ¿Es posible usar librerias compartidas lib*.so con bash?

Tags: bash

Sé que con python se pueden utilizar haciendo uso de [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#loading-shared-libraries) y me surgió la duda de si se podrían usar de alguna forma en un script de bash. He estado buscando información pero no he encontrado nada por lo que supongo que no se puede.
¿Hay forma de hacer uso de ellas?

Comment: Hasta dónde sé no. Una estrategia posible sería encapsular la llamada en un programa que lea los parámetros desde la entrada estándar y el eventual retorno lo presente por la salida estándar, e invocar el mismo en bash como cualquier comando.

Answer (score 1):

Una librería es un archivo que representa un módulo que implementa un conjunto de funciones comunes. Por ejemplo en el header "stdio" (standard input/output) parte de la librería estándar del lenguaje C (libc) se proveen funciones comunes para el manejo de entrada salida como printf, scanf, fopen, fread, fwrite y más. Las librerías permiten que ciertas funciones de uso común por muchos programas puedan ser reutilizadas en lugar de reimplementadas en cada desarrollo.

Al momento de compilar un programa, éste puede hacer uso de cualquier librería disponible, donde cada una de ellas puede ser enlazada de forma estática o dinámica por el linker (ld). Cuando una librería se enlaza de manera estática, esta pasa a formar parte del binario ejecutable. Ahora bien, es común que diferentes programas hagan uso de una misma librería, con lo cual hacer que cada uno de ellos mantenga su propia copia de una misma librería es ineficiente. De modo simplificado, es preferible que todos ellos compartan una misma copia de la librería. Es por ello que se permite el enlazado dinámico. De esta forma, en lugar del ejecutable contener su propia copia de una librería, se enlaza a una librería compartida. Al momento de ejecutar el programa, el loader (programa que se encarga de cargar programas en memoria) se da cuenta que éste hace uso de librerías compartidas y pasa el control al dynamic linker/loader (ld.so) para resolver cada una de ellas.

Cuando una librería compartida es instalada correctamente, todos los programas que inician a partir de ese momento automáticamente utilizarán la nueva librería compartida (o versión). Sin embargo en la práctica es mucho más flexible y sofisticado que esto, ya que la estrategia adoptada por Linux permite actualizar una librería y aún soportar programas que requieran una versión anterior, no compatible hacia atrás, de la misma; sobrescribir una librería o incluso sólo una función específica de una librería cuando se ejecuta un programa en particular; y hacer todo esto mientras los programas están en ejecución utilizando las librerías existentes.

A continuación encontrarás [más información](https://www.linuxito.com/gnu-linux/nivel-basico/1083-librerias-compartidas-variables-de-entorno-y-permisos-en-linux) al respecto.